# How to add user's information on a JWT?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'am using JWT to authenticate users but I want also to add some informations to the token like the username.

This is how I create the tokens after I've authenticated the user :

```
app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res){
    User.findOne({
      username: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user){

      if(!user){
        console.log('Authentication failed. User not found');
      }
      else if(user){
        if(user.password != req.body.password){
          console.log('Authentication failed. Wrong password');
        }
        else{

          var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('secretWord'), {
            expiresIn : 10800,
          });

          res.send({
            token: token
          });
        }
      }
    })
  });
```

How can I associate a username to the token? I tried :

```
var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('secretWord'), {
                expiresIn : 10800,
                username : user.username
              });
```

But that throws an error : "ValidationError: "username" is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add details you want like this

```
var token = jwt.sign(user.name,user.email, app.get('secretWord'), {
        expiresIn : 10800,
      });
```

don't pass the user object in `jwt.sign` because it contains crucial information like `password`, `session_tokens` etc. so Sign only the information which is necessary like `name`, `email`, `role`, `user_type` etc. like above I have given the solution

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to insert the username into jwt's payload as an independent variable.

However better practice is to use the user object to generate the token. With this approach you can easily find the user if you have a token taken that the token will contain information about user's properties. Check this link on how to do this easily:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

You can skip straight to "Authenticating and Creating a Token", there's a good example on how to do this in node.js.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend passing the `user` record from the database as the payload like that! That would lead to your user's password being included in the token. JWT payloads aren't encrypted, so if your token leaked, having the password in there would be bad news.

Comment: Oh I'am already using the user object to generate the token... So how can I retrieve the username from the token after that?

Comment: Create a new object, then use that as the payload: `var payload = { username: user.username };`

Comment: @JoeClay Yes I'am aware of that, but that's only for learning purposes so I'am not very punctilious about that.

Comment: @Mit: Yeah, it's fine if it's not a production app - just don't want people thinking it's a good practice in general :)

Comment: @JoeClay yuDev said that I didn't need a playload since I've generated the token from the user object. Do you know how I can retrieve the username from the token on the client-side?

Comment: @Mit: If you generate the token from the user object, the user object *is* the payload. You can decode the token on the client using https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode (or just look at the [source code](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/master/lib/index.js) - it's tiny).

Comment: @JoeClay I completely agree with you that having the password inside the jwt is a bad practice. I also never recommended you doing so. When I suggested to create your payload from user object I didn't imply having your password stored within.